# Bionic Beaver Distribution for Mac 64-bit PowerPC

Tags: 64-bit, mac, powerpc, 18.04

Will there be a Bionic Beaver Desktop distribution for the Mac G5 64-bit PowerPC?  I have been unable to get 16.04 to work.

Comment: Desktop or Server edition?  Server has a powerpc distribution in the daily ISO builds, but Desktop does not.

Comment: Desktop - I understand the 64bit PPC image would come later but wanting to know "if" rather than "when"

Comment: I don't see any PowerPC desktop builds.  Server has PPC builds, but I don't think Desktop is doing any.  I'll ask around./

Comment: There are no more PPC builds of standard Ubuntu on consumer platforms (the server ISOs are built for IBM server systems, not sure if they'd run well on the older Mac Server boxes or not). I think Ubuntu Mate still generates PPC ISOs though, and maybe a few other flavors.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 16.04 is for Mac PPC and Power5.  Hopefully there will be an 18.04 Mate desktop.

Comment: You might find [this](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/powerpc&prev=search) useful..

Answer (score 1):

18.04 is still in beta. You would be better off getting 16.04 to work on the IBM Power PC properly first and then upgrade later.

Here is one [IBM Site for setting up Ubuntu](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W51a7ffcf4dfd_4b40_9d82_446ebc23c550/page/Installing%20of%20Ubuntu%20LE(Little%20Endian)%20%20on%20bare-metal%20IBM%20Power%20Scale-out%20Systems) on the Power PC. It's the first one I found and you might have to google search it a bit more.

Going to an IBM site for support is a good option. Another is reporting bugs through Launchpad. [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ppc64el/Recommendations) already has a page devoted to IBM Power PC and recommendations not to use `btrfs`, etc. based on Launchpad bug reports.

Comment: Mac G5 PPC.  Unable to get 16.04 graphics to work on two different types of graphic cards.  Have given up on 16.04.

Comment: @JamesLawrence Oh it's Apple using the IBM Power PC platform instead of Intel Platform. That certainly adds an extra level of complexity. On the IBM Linux Developer's website linked above they do discuss setting up nVidia via Docker. Anyway you would get more targeted audience by putting machine specs into your question.

Comment: Understood and sorry.  I was unaware there was a IBM PowerPC platform.  Don't use IBM anything since the PC Junior.

Comment: Ha I forgot about the IBM PC Junior, we used to have one for logging out-going long distance calls, numbers and call length for inter-departmental billing. I didn't know Apple was using the IBM Power PC chipset which first came out in the 1980s or 1990s. So long ago...

Comment: The IBM site link does not seem to show any relevant info. Maybe the site structure was changed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO unless I want to try and make a nice server out of my PowerMac G5.  Will give that a try.

Thanks to all for leading me to the correct Bionic Beaver water hole.

Comment: On the IBM website I linked in my answer many point out how they can install redhat or another Linux distro perfectly fine but have problems with Ubuntu. You should not give up on your PowerMac for a working Linux Desktop Distro.